# Помогите разобраться с array и hashmap

Tags: java, android

Нужно сделать так, чтобы программа могла работать с массивами из ресурсов, но чтобы имена массивов не были заранее строго предопределены в коде самой программы.

Мне посоветовали использовать `HashMap`, но я не до конца понимаю, как его использовать в моём случае.

```
 Map <String, String[]> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
 int current = 1;
```

В ресурсах имеем массив формата имя (будет одинаковым для всех массивов) и номер (будет меняться).

```
 String wpqp = Integer.toString(current);
 hashmap.put (wpqp, "getResouces().getStringArray(R.array.somearray)" + Integer.toString(current));
```

Получаю ошибку о том, что `String` не может быть конвертирован в `String[]`. Скорее всего, решение очень простое, но я всё равно не могу его найти самостоятельно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала формируете название Вашего массива, который хранится в ресурсах:

```
String arrayName = "somearray" + current;
```

Потом получаете идентификатор ресурса (в данном случае массива строк) по сформированному названию:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(arrayName, "array", getPackageName());
```

А далее по идентификатору получаете сам массив:

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(resId);
```

Все вышеизложенное справедливо для случая, когда в `strings.xml` прописан массив вида:

```
<string-array name="somearray1">
    <item>text_1</item>
    <item>text_2</item>
    <item>text_3</item>
</string-array>
```

и `current == 1`.

Comment: Как я только не пробовал - программа всё равно не может найти ресурс. Вы уверены, что правильно написали код?

Comment: @user3807779, Обновил пост.

Comment: А из-за чего это может быть: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x0 ? Вроде правильно всё написал, всё проверил, никаких опечаток нет

Comment: @user3807779, Покажите весь код и содержание файла `strings.xml`.

Comment: Залил на pastebin http://pastebin.com/yWrt4kUx , позже в шапку кину.

Comment: @user3807779, Вот эту строку `String chastring = "R.array.chapter" + current;` замените на эту `String chastring = "chapter" + current;`.

Comment: вопрос немного не по теме, но есть ли ограничение на длину имени массива?

Comment: @user3807779, Я таким вопросом не задавался.